# How to write d.ts file for unreachable remote JS module & how to use it?

Tags: typescript

I'm using some NPM modules (non-typed JS) which are served in private repository.  I cannot get the source or modify it (it's only available on CI server).  But I have good API documents of them instead.

I believe it will be helpful if I can write some d.ts files for those libraries, but after days searching around internet I couldn't find a guide about how to put a d.ts file away from the original JS file.

Is this possible to do?

For example, I have below files:

```
[1] /proj/node_modules/priv-lib/index.js (READONLY)
[2] /proj/src/my.ts
[3] /proj/src/declarations/priv-lib.d.ts
```

While file [1] has API as below (in JS usage):

```
const privLib = require('priv-lib')

privLib(xxx)  // itself is a function
privLib.anotherFn(yyy)
privLib.someConstant
```

I want to write declarations for file [1] in file [3] then use it in file [2].

---

### Update 1

OK, now I've got a possible solution:

```
// [3] /proj/src/declarations/priv-lib.d.ts

declare module 'priv-lib' {
  function privLib(xxx: any): any

  namespace privLib {
    function anotherFn(yyy: any): any

    const someConstant: string
  }

  export = privLib
}
```

And then

```
// [2] /proj/src/my.ts

import privLib = require('priv-lib')
privLib(1)
privLib.anotherFn(2)
privLib.someConstant
```

Seems no need of `///<reference />`

I don't know if this is the correct way (at least no side-effect and not deprecated) to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct. If you are using TypeScript < 2.0 you will need a `///<reference />`.

If you are using TypeScript >= 2.0 you will NOT need a `///<reference />` in some cases:

- `@types/priv-lib` is available as an npm module
- The `priv-lib` includes `typigns`

Because that is not the case, you will need a `///<reference />`.